# Encode and decode .gif file to be used with pyglet and made into .exe with pyinstaller

Tags: python, base64, pyinstaller, animated-gif, pyglet

I want to bake a `.gif` file into `.exe` with **pyinstaller**. From my research I have to encode the gif to a string and decode that string for this to be possible. Encoding the string and decoding the string is working. I get an error when trying to use it as a animation resource in **pyglet**. Something in the encoding-decoding has broken the gif? If there is another preferred way of doing this please let me know!

Step1

```
import base64

with open("test.gif", "rb") as imageFile:
    image = base64.b64encode(imageFile.read())
    print(image)
```

Step2

Saving this string in a .py file like this:

```
image = b'AWggsegsegs/....'
```

Step3

```
import pyglet
import base64
from gif_string import image


decodedgif = base64.b64decode(image) # Works this far
animation = pyglet.resource.animation(decodedgif) # Error here
sprite = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(decodedgif)
```

Error message reads

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...pyglet\resource.py", line 583, in animation
    identity = self._cached_animations[name]
  File "...AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\weakref.py", line 131, in __getitem__
    o = self.data[key]()
KeyError: b'GIF89a
...
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\pyglet\resource.py", line 435, in file
    location = self._index[name]
KeyError: b'GIF89a\
...
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\..., line 7, in <module>
    animation = pyglet.resource.animation(decodedgif) # Error here
  File "...\pyglet\resource.py", line 585, in animation
    animation = pyglet.image.load_animation(name, self.file(name))
  File "...\pyglet\resource.py", line 438, in file
    raise ResourceNotFoundException(name)
pyglet.resource.ResourceNotFoundException: Resource "b'GIF89a\x00\
...
...f9\x88\xc0\xbe\xa4O"o\xcf\xe5\x81\x00\x00;'" was not found on the path.
  Ensure that the filename has the correct captialisation.
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `pyglet.resource.animation()` which can only load files, you should use `pyglet.image.load_animation()`. Its optional `File` parameter supports [file-like objects](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-file-like-object), so you should construct one using [`io.BytesIO()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#binary-i-o) and pass it there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried out what you said and got it running without errors. However the gif playing is just a big white square blinking
``import pyglet
    import base64
    from gif_string import *
    from io import BytesIO

    image1 = base64.b64decode(image)
    decodedgif = BytesIO(image1)
    animation = pyglet.image.load_animation('gif.gif', file=decodedgif)
    sprite = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(animation)
    win = pyglet.window.Window(width=sprite.width, height=sprite.height)

    win.clear()
    sprite.draw()
    pyglet.app.run()``

Comment: @Tireless22 That\`s the expected output when you try to use it like that. `win.clear()` and `sprite.draw()` shall be wrapped in an `on_draw()` event, [see here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/51814). Animated sprites need to be… well… animated =)